# How do I get the heigh and width of a window after it is resized and apply it to the overlay already set?

Tags: jquery, popup, window, height, width

Getting the default width and height.

```
//Get the screen height and width
var maskHeight = $(window).height();
var maskWidth = $(window).width();

$(window).resize(function(){
maskHeight = $(window).height();
maskWidth = $(window).width();          
});
```

Setting the mask to be the stored width and height of the document

```
//Set height and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
$('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});        
$('#mask').css('display','block');
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.innerWidth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will resize your `mask` on the fly:

```
$(window).resize(function(){   
    $('#mask').css({'width':$(window).width() + 'px','height':$(window).height() + 'px'});       
});
```

Comment: Is there a bug in IE for this? If I start out non full screen and I hit maximize sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't?

Comment: Shouldn't be. Check if the handler called in this scenario.